# Find equivalence classes and quotient set of $(x,y)R(w,z)\iff2(x-w)=z-y$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, equivalence-relations, quotient-set

Let $R$ be an equivalence relation defined on $\Bbb{N}^2$, where $$(x,y)R(w,z)\iff2(x-w)=z-y.$$ **Find equivalence classes and quotient set.**

---

First, we can express $2(x-w)=z-y$ as $$2x+y=2w+z.$$ So, for example $[(1,1)]=\{(x,y)\in\Bbb{N}^2\mid2x+y=3\}=\{(1,1)\}$.

Also, $[(1,2)]=\{(x,y)\in\Bbb{N}^2\mid2x+y=4\}=\{(1,2)\}$.

In addition, $[(1,3)]=\{(x,y)\in\Bbb{N}^2\mid2x+y=5\}=\{(1,3),(2,1)\}$.

$[(1,4)]=\{(x,y)\in\Bbb{N}^2\mid2x+y=6\}=\{(1,4),(2,2)\}$.

$[(1,5)]=\{(x,y)\in\Bbb{N}^2\mid2x+y=7\}=\{(1,5),(2,3),(3,1)\}$.

$[(1,6)]=\{(x,y)\in\Bbb{N}^2\mid2x+y=8\}=\{(1,6),(2,4),(3,2)\}$.

---

We can guess that $$[(a,b)]=\{(x,y)\in\Bbb{N}^2\mid2x+y=2a+b,\;a\in\Bbb{N},b=2-a\}\cup\{(1,1),(1,2)\}.$$ I don't think it has a nice expression. I am not sure how to find the quotient set.

Any help?

Comment: The equivalence classes are the intersections with $\Bbb N^2$ of lines in the plane whose slope is $-2$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thank you! Well, it has sense since $y=-2x+c$, $c\in\Bbb{N}$. It is a family of lines in the plane. So what can we write as a generic equivalence class $[(a,b)]$?

Comment: Straight from the definition: $[\langle a,b\rangle]=\left\{\langle m,n\rangle\in\Bbb N^2:2m+n=2a+b\right\}$. Or you can note that for each integer $n\ge 3$ there is an equivalence class $C_n=\{\langle a,n-2a\rangle:a\in\Bbb N\text{ and }2a\le n\}$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott thanks. What about the quotient set? Is the set of all equivalence classes. We don't have to repeat any equivalence class. So, should it be $\Bbb{N}^2/R=\{[(a,b)]\mid a\in\Bbb{N},\;b=\text{?}\}$? What is the value of $b$?

Comment: I would say simply that it’s $\{C_n:n\ge 3\}$, where $C_n$ is as I defined it above.